# MySqlCommand: how to get title into comboboxes

Tags: c#, mysql

Need help here,
i need to get the title into the comboboxes named cntpaginaBX and prmopaginaBX.
with one it works but when i try both .. It fails.
What i want to know is the "MySqlCommand".
how do i fix it because it doesnt take content, promo, sqlConn togheter.

```
        MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection("Database=joshua;
        Data Source=localhost; User Id='root'; Password=''");
        string content = "SELECT title FROM content";
        string promo = "SELECT title FROM promo";
        MySqlCommand myCommando = new MySqlCommand(content, promo, sqlConn); <-----here
        MySqlDataReader sqlReader;
        object cont;
        object prom;

        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlReader = myCommando.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                cont = sqlReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                cntpaginaBX.Items.Add(cont);
                prom = sqlReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                prmopaginaBX.Items.Add(prom);
            }

            sqlReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message, "Fout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `MySqlCommand` is used to run a ***single*** query. You cannot simply run two queries together. Each query needs to be a completely separate `MySqlCommand`.

```
string content = "SELECT title FROM content";
MySqlCommand contentCommand = new MySqlCommand(content, sqlConn);
try
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlReader = contentCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        cont = sqlReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        cntpaginaBX.Items.Add(cont);
    }

    sqlReader.Close();
}
```

And then:

```
string promo = "SELECT title FROM promo";
MySqlCommand promoCommand = new MySqlCommand(promo, sqlConn);
try
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlReader = promoCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
            prom = sqlReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            prmopaginaBX.Items.Add(prom);
    }

    sqlReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Follow problem is in the prmopaginaBX the titles from content are showing up

Comment: Ok i got it, found some not deleted lines